# Failed to recognize storage pool after reinstalling windows 10

Tags: windows-10, storage-pool

I have reinstalled Windows 10 since the SSD was failed. Before it fails, I have a storage pool running on RAID 1. But after the re-installation, it can't detect the pool. The physical drives are not damaged. Any solution to this without having to reset the disk?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you disconnect the storage drives while you re-installed Windows? If not W10 reinstall may have written something to one of the disks, which would cause your problem.

Since it is raid one you can disconnect the drives from the raid controller and use a sata to usb adapter to copy your data to another drive, then rebuild the storage pool and copy the data back. You may have to use disk management to import a single disk from raid one array.